# An internal error occurred during: "Compute launch button tooltip"

Tags: android, eclipse

First, I'm aware that there is a similar post made on September 21 where the victim ended up having to reinstall Eclipse and all that goes with it.  I'm hoping for a less difficult solution...

I've been working on my project for a few months now and today when making a routing compile it came up with the error : An internal error occurred during: "Compute launch button tooltip". Along with forty or so other errors that make no sense.  The bitmap below shows the errors.  I had just made a simple change to an if statement.  Now, nothing I do will get rid of these errors.

Unlike the previous post, the other project in this workspace gets the identical errors.  Projects in other workspaces are compiling ok.  I'm trying to import the project into a new workspace but having major problems with that.

I'm reasonably new to Android and Eclipse (I use C# and visual studio normally).  Does this kind of think happen often?  thanks, Gary

EDIT: I got the project running by creating a new workspace and importing it into the new workspace.  So, apparently it was the workspace that was somehow corrupt?

[image: Eclipse error image]

Comment: Can you post the line (and surrounding code) you modified that resulted in these errors? Does it work if you change it back?

Comment: Yes, I did change it back - to no avail.  See my EDIT.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking at the wrong problem. Your error log is sorted by message, but it should be sorted by date to really find the latest error. And then your real problem might be the "invalid preference page path: XML syntax".

Did you recently update your ADT installation? And do you have some very old version of Eclipse maybe? Because there can be quite some trouble using old Eclipse versions with ADT, which don't correctly recognize the dependencies to the Eclipse Webservice Tools (which again provide XML tooling).

Comment: I installed Eclipse about 3 months ago so its recent.  None of the errors make any sense and they are identical for the other project in this workspace.  It seems that the workspace has become corrupt.  I have the project working now in a new workspace so maybe it's behind me now.